# Multiple Instances of same Application as a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have an application that manages the heavy processing for my project, and need to convert it to a "Windows Service."  I need to allow running multiple <strike>versions</strike> instances of the application processing, which seems to be a fairly normal requirement.

I can see at least three approaches to do this:

1. Create a single installed directory (EXE, DLLs, config) but install as multiple *Services* instances from it.
2. Have a single *Services* instance spawn multiple instances of itself after launching, a la Apache.
3. Have a single *Services* instance spawn multiple threads that work within the same process space.

My intention was approach #1, but I kept tripping over the limitations, both in design and especially documentation for *Services*:

- Are parameters *ever* passed to **OnStart()** by the normal Services mechanisms on an unattended system? If so, when/why?
- Passing run-time parameters via the *ImageKey* registry seems a kludge, is there a better mechanism?
- I got the app to install/uninstall itself as a pair of services ("XYZ #1", "XYZ #2", ...), using the *ImageKey* to hand it a command line parameter instance number ("-x 1", "-x 2") but I was missing something.  When attempting to start the service, it would fail with "*The executable program that this service is configured to run in does not implement the service*.

So, the questions:

1. Is there a concise description of what happens when a service starts, specifically for those situations where the *ServiceName* is not hard-coded (see Q above).
2. Has anyone used approach #1 successfully?  Any comments?

*NOTE:* I've side-stepped the problem by using approach #3, so I can't justify much time figuring this out.   But I thought someone might have information on how to implement #1 -- or good reasons why it isn't a good idea.

**[Edit]** I originally had a 4th option (*install multiple copies of the application on the hard drive*) but I removed it because it just feels, um, hackish.  That's why I said "*at least three approaches*".

However, unless the app is recompiled, it must dynamically set its ServiceName, hence that has the solution to the third bullet/problem above.  So, unless an instance needed to alter it's install files, #1 should work fine with *N* config files in the directory and a registry entry indicating which the instance should use.

Answer (score 7):

Though I can't answer your questions specific to option #1, I can tell you that option #2 worked very well for us.  We wanted to create an app domain for each 'child' service to run under and for each of them to use a different configuration file.  In our service's config file we stored the app domains to start and the configuration file to use.  So for each entry we simply created the app domain, set the configuration file etc and off we went.  This separation of configuration allowed us to easily specify the ports and log file locations uniquely for each instance.  Of additional benefit to us was that we wrote our 'child service' as a command-line exe and simply called the AppDomain's ExecuteAssembly() on a new thread for each 'child' service.  The only 'clunk' in the solution was shutdown, we didn't bother to create a 'good' solution for it.

**Update Feb, 2012**

Some time ago we started using 'named' services (like SQL Server).  I detailed the entire process on my blog in a series "Building a Windows Service – [Part 1](http://csharptest.net/837/building-a-windows-service-part-1-getting-started/) through [Part 7](http://csharptest.net/990/building-a-windows-service-part-7-finishing-touches/)".  They take you through creating a command-line/windows service hybrid complete with self-installation.  The following goals where met:

- Building a service that can also be used from the console
- Proper event logging of service startup/shutdown and other activities
- Allowing multiple instances by using command-line arguments
- Self installation of service and event log
- Proper event logging of service exceptions and errors
- Controlling of start-up, shutdown and restart options
- Handling custom service commands, power, and session events
- Customizing service security and access control

A complete Visual Studio project template is available in the last article of the series [Building a Windows Service – Part 7: Finishing touches](http://csharptest.net/990/building-a-windows-service-part-7-finishing-touches/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Multiple Instance .NET Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx)

Comment: That's the "install app multiple times" solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is option #4 that I'm successfully using in my project aka "named instances".

Every installation of your app has custom name and each installation has its own service. They are completely independent and isolated from each other. MS SQL Server is using this model if you try to install it multiple time on single machine.

Comment: Actually, that isn't just adding *Service* instances, but is adding *installations* each with a different ServiceName.   

But since this approach solves the "dynamically set ServiceName" issue I hit, it means #1 can be done.  However, it seems to me that #1 would be easier (if only for the end user) -- just install the files/package once and then install multiple services from it. 
*Presuming the instances don't require extensive differences in files in the install directory*

Comment: I know but you said you need more services because there are possibly multiple versions of your application. why to make things complicated by dumping all versions into single folder. If you assume that all your versions are going to be compatible in the future with what is in your single install directory, then go ahead but it's dangerous thing to assume something in software development unless it's based on some solid mathematical foundation and this is not :)

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I had a typo: I meant multiple _instance_ of the _same version_, not "multiple versions" as I originally stated.  There will never be more than one version installed.