# Two windows services in the same time and the same dll's

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to turn on two services in the same time and i use the same .dll's with both of them:

get strangest error:

```
windows service .net Cannot start service on computer '.'.
```

this error is after the first service is up and running, 
How should i resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot start multiple instances of the same registered service, you need a different service instance. Here are some options  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370539/multiple-instances-of-same-application-as-a-windows-service

Comment: The service failed to start. Impossible to say much more without seeing some code or more detailed error information from the event log.

Comment: @Cody Gray That's it this is the error i get, no more no less.

Comment: Heres some links to work around the problem.    http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx    http://igorbrejc.net/development/c/multiple-instance-windows-service-in-c    http://www.runeibsen.dk/?p=153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually going to need different names / paths for the two instances. The limitation is coming from windows. The alternative is to host in something like TopShelf which will allow you to quickly scale vertically in this way.